# Change panel display using inside same window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]
[image]

Try to make start game after click "Start".

How can I start game inside same window?

```
public class Object extends JFrame {
    public Object() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new Main());
        // add(new Board());
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), getHeight()));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Object();
    }
}
```

Comment: use a [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and extend from [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) instead of [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). Also rename your class to something else rather than `Object` since it may attract problems or confusion with Oracle's [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout`. You can swap panels when you click the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.